# How can sound work when pulseaudio is not running?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, kde, alsa, headphones

I'm having a little trouble with sound on my Ubuntu 18.04 system. 
For setup, first, I've installed default Ubuntu, then xfce-desktop, then kde-desktop.

Now, since I'm doing development, I normally graphically login as root. 
So when I work with gnome, and want some sound, I have to manually start pulseaudio.

So far, so little of a problem. 
But after installing KDE, I have no countrol over sound on the audio applet/symbol/widget.

I can also start pulseaudio manually, and start pavucontrol, but I get no devices there, other than the dummy device.

The funny thing is, sound works, just that I can't control the volume with the kde volume manager/applet/symbol/widet. 
There's also no pulseaudio-daemon running. 
I've killed them all, and the sound still works - so I assume it somehow runs on ALSA.

Now when I plugin the headphones - it mutes, and I can't unmute. 
I've discovered I can change the volume on the console with "alsamixer". 
But I can't unmute the headphones there. I turn-up the headphone volume on alaxamixer, and it's still muted.

Anybody knows how I can unmute the headphones with ALSA, or why else it doesn't work ?

Or how/where I can switch between ALSA and pulseaudio ? 
(to-from-andBack) 
And how can I see what the system is using ?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, never mind.

```
amixer set -c 0 Headphone 100 unmute
amixer set -c 0 Master 100 unmute
```

or to mute:

```
amixer set -c 0 Headphone 100 mute
amixer set -c 0 Master 100 mute
```

and to get the audio-control working:

```
apt-get install kmix

kmix
```

to increase volume

```
amixer set Master 30%+
```

to decrease volume

```
amixer set Master 30%-
```

Comment: You should be anle to do all that in `alsamixer`.